# Will it reveal a website between a link shortener and a redirect?

Tags: php, redirect

so I can easily edit some links, I was thinking about having my website act as the middle part, where I store the links in the database and use PHP to redirect (kind of like a shortener but probably with more basic code)

I did a test with two URL shorteners, and to me it seemed like the middle one wasn't revealed at all, however, I don't know what would happen if one went slow (like the browser could possibly say receiving data from x or actually put the URL in the bar). Also, even if it wasn't anything obvious, would you still be able to see headers received from the site or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser will know. The first one just returns a response with a redirect header containing the new url. The browser will use this url to make a new request to the second redirect url.

You can <strike>probably</strike> see this happening when you inspect the Network tab in the developer tools (F12) in your browser.